# C# UDP Socket Bind Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udpclient, mesh-network

I am attempting to create a program for a wireless mesh (adhoc in all but name). Most of the network will deal with TCP messaging but to determine all neighbor IPs (as they will be unknown on startup), I choose to use UDP Broadcast for the initial discovery messages. That code, for the most part, is irrelevant as initial testing appeared to work and currently I do not call it.

The following is the section to receive and register the neighbors' IPs.

```
protected override void ReceiveMessageUDP()
    {
        while (live)
        {
            try
            {
                UdpListener = new UdpClient(_PORTRECEIVE);
                UdpListener.EnableBroadcast = true;
                Socket socket = UdpListener.Client;
                IPEndPoint endPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, _PORTRECEIVE);
                IPEndPoint endPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORTRECEIVE);
                socket.Bind(endPoint2);
                socket.Listen(25);
                Socket connected = socket.Accept();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length = connected.Receive(buffer);

                IPAddress remoteIP = ((IPEndPoint)connected.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
                if (!ipAddresses.Contains(remoteIP))
                    ipAddresses.Add(remoteIP);

                Message.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, length));
            }
            catch (SocketException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode); }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

I have tested with both IPEndPoints and regardless of how I set it up, the Bind fails with SocketException.ErrorCode 10022 [Windows Socket Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(VS.85).aspx). It is an invalid argument but I am confused about what that means as the argument required is an EndPoint.

This fails on the first run so it's not like I am attempting to rebind the port.

Answer (score 1):

You've already bound the port to the `UdpCLient` when you constructed it.  You cannot then bind the same port to a separate `IPEndPoint`.

```
UdpListener = new UdpClient(_PORTRECEIVE);  // binds port to UDP client
...
IPEndPoint endPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORTRECEIVE);
socket.Bind(endPoint2);  // attempts to bind same port to end point
```

If you want to do it this way, build and bind the `IPEndPoint` and then construct the `UdpClient` with it instead of the port.

```
IPEndPoint endPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORTRECEIVE);
socket.Bind(endPoint2);  // bind port to end point

UdpListener = new UdpClient(endPoint2);  // binds port to UDP client via endpoint
```

I am not sure why you are also setting up another end point `endPoint1` on the same port.  That will likely cause problems down the line, if and when you try to use this.

Comment: I'm 95% new to doing any TCP/UDP/Socket anything, so I've been flying blind for about 2 weeks figuring this out. Once I create the UdpClient with the EndPoint, I then bind the Socket to a secondary Endpoint?

Comment: The logic above (my version) binds the socket to that endpoint and then sets up a client on the endpoint - socket is still bound at that point. You can also use port id = 0 and the system will use any free local port, that option's probably going to be easier for you on `endPoint1`. Take a look at the example code on MSDN here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k227d11f.aspx - there are tons of examples that could help you figure this out. Take a look here for general TCP/UDP starter info - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c19ex43h.aspx

Comment: I create tons of variables like that while testing - just giving them different numbers at the end to quickly choose between them while testing. As for the program - I changed it with your suggestions, trying the first one then the second and finally using 0 as the port for the UdpClient. I received the same error code for the socket.Bind again.

Comment: Figured it out, UDP doesn't allow binding or stuff.

Comment: @Scott S - glad to hear you are over the hump on this

Comment: re: **UDP doesn't allow binding**. Better to say "doesn't require binding".  It is allowed to Bind a Socket that is not already Bound.  And you may want to do so if you want to control which EndPoint is used to send the UDP message.  The issue is that **UdpClient** already call **Client.Bind(...)**.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with steve. However, you state that

> "UDP doesn't allow binding or stuff."

But it does. You can bind any socket (udp or not) to any network interface. Steve gave a hint to achieve it. This is how I do it:

```
LocalEP = new IPEndPoint(<local IP>, _PORTRECEIVE) ;
listener = New UdpClient(LocalEP) ;
```

As steve pointed out, once an UdpClient is instantiated, it does not allow rebinding to another interface. The trick is telling the constructor to bind to de interface you want beforehand. Substitute  by the IP address of the local interface you wish to use.

Sure, this is only useful when you have (or might have) several network interfaces and want to use a specific one. Otherwise, I've seen that the interface with a valid gateway to the internet is usually the one to which clients bind by default. And this is usually the correct one.

Roberto

Comment: Also useful if you want to send from a specific port, even if you are bound to IPAddress.Any.